# How to reload window after Hubspot Messenger().run() message closes?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-delete, hubspot

I'm writing an MVC app and I really need a reload window after message (both error and success) closes.
How can I achieve this?

Actually, I'm trying this code on my button click, but no luck:

```
    Messenger().run({
        successMessage: 'Record Removed!',
        errorMessage: 'Error',
        progressMessage: 'Removing record...',
        events: {
            "click": function () {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    }, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            return errorThrown;
        }
    });
```

CodePen to test: http://codepen.io/larissa/pen/rjOpRM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide to change approach to this solution. Thanks to @codenut for the help!
Using this code, works for me.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.deleteButton', function (e) {
    var urlDelete = $(this).data('url');
    var table = $('#' + $(this).data('grid')).DataTable();

    Messenger().run({
        successMessage: 'Row removed!',
        progressMessage: 'Removing row...'
    }, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: urlDelete,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             return errorThrown;
        },
        complete: function () {
            table.ajax.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: nice but what about reload on error. And i have neutralized your question ;)

Comment: @codenut, with this approach, I made a partial reload, only for the grid affected by delete operation. your help was essencial to this solution!

Comment: Glad to hear that

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but try this

```
   Messenger().run({
        successMessage: 'Record Removed!',
        errorMessage: 'Error',
        progressMessage: 'Removing record...',
        events: {
            "click": function () {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    }, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        error: function (data) {
                 location.reload();
        },
        success: function (data) {
               location.reload();
         },

    });
```

Comment: Thanks @codenut, but using this approach, reload occurs **before** ajax execution.

Comment: Thanks again, @codenut, with this new approach, in case of error, specific messages returned by MVC are not shown.

Comment: but what about success

Comment: why someone downvote this post? what is wrong with it?

Comment: did you not see the CodePen link? Is there something less useful than this? come on! :^/